# gdb not stopping at even trivial breakpoints

Tags: ffmpeg, gdb, mingw

I am trying to debug `ffplay` (a debug build) compiled using `mingw-w64` on `msys2` on Windows 7 64bit. I tried setting breakpoints using `gdb`, and they seem to be set fine, but the program does not stop. So i tried issuing `start`, and again it didn't stop. I tried manually setting a breakpoint at `main`, but it still didn't stop. I verified that `main` is found, and it is. Here is a portion of the session. Any explanation what might cause this?

```
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x140013f7c: file C:/Users/bubaruch/Documents/projects/ffmpeg/ffmpeg/ffplay.c, line 3756.
Starting program: C:\Users\bubaruch\Documents\projects\ffmpeg\b2\ffplay_g.exe
[New Thread 7752.0x275c]
ffplay version 2.8.git Copyright (c) 2003-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.2.0 (Rev4, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --disable-doc --disable-optimizations
  libavutil      55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
  libavcodec     57. 15.100 / 57. 15.100
  libavformat    57. 14.100 / 57. 14.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
  libavfilter     6. 15.100 /  6. 15.100
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
Simple media player
usage: ffplay [options] input_file

An input file must be specified
Use -h to get full help or, even better, run 'man ffplay'
[Inferior 1 (process 7752) exited with code 01]

(gdb) l main
3748       return 1;
3749    }
3750
3751    /* Called from the main */
3752    int main(int argc, char **argv)
3753    {
3754        int flags;
3755        VideoState *is;
3756        char dummy_videodriver[] = "SDL_VIDEODRIVER=dummy";
3757

(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 2 at 0x140013f7c: file C:/Users/bubaruch/Documents/projects/ffmpeg/ffmpeg/ffplay.c, line 3756.

(gdb) r
Starting program: C:\Users\bubaruch\Documents\projects\ffmpeg\b2\ffplay_g.exe
[New Thread 15388.0x3278]
ffplay version 2.8.git Copyright (c) 2003-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.2.0 (Rev4, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --disable-doc --disable-optimizations
  libavutil      55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
  libavcodec     57. 15.100 / 57. 15.100
  libavformat    57. 14.100 / 57. 14.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
  libavfilter     6. 15.100 /  6. 15.100
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
Simple media player
usage: ffplay [options] input_file

An input file must be specified
Use -h to get full help or, even better, run 'man ffplay'
[Inferior 1 (process 15388) exited with code 01]
```

Answer (score 1):

From [docs](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Starting.html):

> The ‘start’ command does the equivalent of setting a temporary
>   breakpoint at the beginning of the main procedure and then invoking
>   the ‘run’ command.

So you're already inside main when you set the breakpoint. It is never reached again, since the program exits at the end of main. Thus, the breakpoint never triggers.

I have the feeling you're trying to set alternate breakpoints deep inside ffmpeg and debug something more specific, and that's not triggering either. Why don't you ask that question instead? The explanation for it is likely very different, probably having to do with inlining.

Comment: I think this doesn't really address his problem.  He typed `start`, which sets a temporary breakpoint on `main` and runs the program.  Being "already in main" doesn't apply.  However the temporary breakpoint doesn't stop.  So, something weird is going on, maybe a gdb bug -- though I don't really know, I'm not familiar with this port.

Comment: It is true that I was trying to debug something deeper down, and the breakpoints weren't being hit. Even though I compiled with no optimizations etc., I suspected it might be something of the sort, so I tested by trying to break at `main`, which should have worked, but didn't work either. I was not in `main` when I ran `start`, it was a new `gdb` session. And as you can see, it ran right through to the end. I checked that `main` is there and not optimized out, and it is (as seen in the post)

Comment: So, let's go into the actual bug that you're seeing. What function are you really trying to debug, does that symbol exist, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the symbols file is out-of-sync with the executable.

gdb tells you that main() is at line 3756. On my system it'd tell you it's at line 3753 (on the "{" line). Maybe somebody edited the source files and compiled it but hasn't re-created the symbols file, thereby making gdb setting breakpoints at unreachable addresses.